# Can I send request after pressing "Enter" in filter? I want to set even on that field

Tags: extjs, filter

Can I send request after pressing "Enter" in filter? I want to set even on that field.
[image]

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html
this is example of filter

Comment: Make sure the question is self contained.

Comment: Well, what is not working ? The "enter" key ? Are you sure your filters are working well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add specialkey listeners

you can find ENTER number In [KeyList](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.EventObject-property-ENTER)

Comment: Why should the OP "Add specialkey listeners"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.